# Tableau pulling one value from table

Tags: datatable, tableau-api

I have a table in Tableau that is based on a MTD calculation.  It gives multiple values for different departs on each day of the month.  This table is linked to another sheet that I click on to choose the value in the table that I want to see.

Right now I only highlight that value in the table.  I want to be able to pull one specific value out and display by itself in the dashboard close to the chart.

How do you pull a value from a table and display.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please see this -> http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask you should elaborate, it is not clear at all what you are asking about.